# My app in iOS was rejected for this reason

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, info.plist

So i tried to submit my app into iTunes Connect, but it was rejected for this reason:

> Guideline 2.3 - Performance
>
> We were unable to install the app on iPhone. The
>   UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a
>   way that the app will not install on an iPhone.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
>   key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your
>   app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device.
>   Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are
>   required and false if they must not be present on the device.
>
> Resources
>
> Please review the Technical Q&A 1397: Understanding the
>   UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key for information on the
>   UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.
>
> You may also wish to review the dictionary keys table in the
>   "Declaring the Required Device Capabilities" section of the App
>   Programming Guide for iOS.

I already checked that information, but i don't now what to put in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key

This is what i have in my info.plist (notice that my app is just made it for iPhone devices)

[image]

So what can i do? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you specifically require armv7? You should delete that entry.

Comment: I just want my app to be available in iPhone device, should i delete that line??? So i leave the blank space??

Answer (score 2):

Various iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch devices use armv7 processors. Setting that value is not what you need to make an iPhone-only app.

Delete that entire "Required device capabilities" entry.

To make an iPhone-only app, simply select "iPhone" for the "Device Family" settings (as opposed to iPad or Universal).

And please note that all iPhone-only apps must also work on iPads as-is. They will run the 1x/2x iPhone compatibility mode. This means your app must also support 3.5" iPhone sizes.